# Using Python Open Source to Create an Organized Picture Library

Tags: python, database

It is the science fair and for this year I want to make something that could actually be used (and maybe get me to the next round). I thought of an online backpack. I have tried to learn a little bit of Python and thought this would be a good language to start with. Basically I want to let pictures of assignments be put into folders organized by classes so you can access work from a mobile device. How can I start on this?

Comment: Are you asking how to write the whole program or just how to set up a programming environment?

Comment: I just need to know how to start it since I am a pretty big newbie and I want to figure it out along the way.